# AWS Lambda: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord, aws-lambda, bundler

I'm using AWS Lambda to run a simple ruby script with a [github project](https://github.com/lorennorman/ruby-on-lambda) that has a framework that suits my needs.

After facing several ruby and bundler version conflicts due to the limitations of [Traveling Ruby](http://phusion.github.io/traveling-ruby/) that is part of the stack.

I'm able to run the script locally successfully but then when I package it and update the Lambda function I get a weird error on the AWS console as I test it:

```
START RequestId: feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0 Version: $LATEST
2017-06-30T15:08:39.144Z    feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0    Starting process: ./app
2017-06-30T15:08:51.403Z    feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0    stderr:
/var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-06-30T15:08:51.403Z    feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0    stderr:
: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord 4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord 4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
from /var/task/lib/app/app.rb:12:in `<main>'

2017-06-30T15:08:51.744Z    feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0    {"errorMessage":"Process \"./app\" exited with code: 1"}
END RequestId: feab102b-5da5-11e7-bf18-739c73eb4ef0
```

In the `db/config.yml`(which it calls `config/database.yml` as it should be defaulted to rails tree) I have set `adapter: postgresql` and the all other required settings.

The code is entirely stored on a `.zip` file and I've unpacked it and was able to find the `lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb` which I guess is extracted on the `/var/task` within the Lambda environment as it shows in logs.

The only thing I can think of is that at the moment of the `require` it is getting lost on the base path and therefore not finding the file to load.

I'd appreciate any insights of anything I may be missing or any clues towards fixing this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends up that the error above is misleading because `activerecord` actually rescues the exception and raises a customized error message and therefore does not reflect the reality happening somewhere else in the stack while loading the `pg` gem. The actual error is this:

```
START RequestId: a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0 Version: $LATEST
2017-07-03T15:38:30.977Z    a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0    Starting process: ./app
2017-07-03T15:38:42.337Z    a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0    stderr:
/var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2017-07-03T15:38:42.456Z    a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0    stderr:
: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/pg-0.21.0/pg_ext.so - libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/pg-0.21.0/pg_ext.so - Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
from /var/task/lib/vendor/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
from /var/task/lib/app/app.rb:12:in `<main>'

2017-07-03T15:38:42.676Z    a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0    {"errorMessage":"Process \"./app\" exited with code: 1"}
END RequestId: a9e88496-6005-11e7-924c-e7c37f2df3e0
```

The real reason is also hidden behind this error. It is not that the `pg_ext.so` was not found as it is there in this very path.

After some more research, the final issue is that `libpg.so.5` itself is the one missing and to fix that I had to add it within Traveling Ruby's libraries path.

Hope that can become helpful to others in the future!